# Why does my VcXsrv crash with "XIO: fatal IO error 110 (Connection timed out) on X server"

Tags: windows, x11

I'm using VcXsrv to display X11 graphics from docker on windows (which I've just updated - and now this problem has started). I've checked the box for "disable access control" but if I leave the connection alone for a while it will fail with the error message below. This also happens during its normal use. This has never happened to be before. What is going on?

XIO:  fatal IO error

```
110 (Connection timed out) on X server "192.168.1.115:0.0"
      after 976 requests (976 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```